# How to go to a specific date in ThinkOrSwim on all open / linked charts

Tags: thinkorswim

I'm using ThinkOrSwim and have many charts with different time frames up at once. I commonly want to go to a specific date.

1. What is the easiest way to go to a specific date on a chart in ThinkOrSwim?
2. Is it possible to have all open charts, or at least the ones that are in the same "linked group", go to that date?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you asked customer support for that product?

Comment: @keshlam Yes, their support doesn't know a way to accomplish this. I was wondering if the community has figured out any work around in the UI, or via ThinkScript, as this seems like a pretty common use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do this thanks to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkorswim/comments/wdks43/is_it_possible_to_chart_a_specific_time_range/). Reposting here in case it helps someone.

Using OnDemand will let you go to a specific date, on all your open charts, while keeping those chart configurations. The right edge of the chart will be the date you input, so you can only see "in the past" from the date you go to. Would be good to keep your date range in the chart, but overall almost everything I needed.

Here are the TOS docs on how to enable OnDemand: https://tickertape.tdameritrade.com/tools/backtest-historical-data-thinkorswimondemand-15667

Note that it will be replaying the tickers, so consider pausing the feed if you want to stay on that date.